# cross domain in cefsharp

Tags: cross-domain, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I used CefSharp for handling 2 scheme: "http" and "uc".
At first I loaded page by http. After that, I called a "uc" link. It occurred the error "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP".

Until now, I can't find any solution. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a section of the chromium embedded guide on this subject:
https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/GeneralUsage#Request_Handling

You need to register your custom "uc" schema and set the "Standard" flag for CORS to work.

Alternatively, instead of using a custom scheme you can register a request handler for "http" and "customdomain" - and you will handle requests for `http://customdomain/*`  and CORS will work just like with http.

For example:

```
var your_factory = XX;

var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme {
    SchemeName = "http",
    SchemeHandlerFactory = your_factory,
    DomainName = "customdomain",
    IsStandard = true
});

Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Comment: Hello Yoshi! I was facing the same problem.
And I am unable to follow on both if your advices.
I am using CEFSHARP not CEF.  
I have already registered one custom scheme but I dont know how / where do I register a request handler for "http"?